# How to avoid returning null after catching an exception?

Tags: java, rest, exception, nullpointerexception, httpclient

I'm writing a REST Client using the HttpClient library in Java.

I wrote this method to post object:

```
public HttpResponse post(URIBuilder uri, Object body) {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(setBaseProps(uri));
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        StringEntity bodyToPost = new StringEntity(g.toJson(body));
        request.setEntity(bodyToPost);

        log.info("Perform POST request to: " + request.getURI().toString());
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("The Character Encoding is not supported!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        log.error("HTTP protocol error!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Some problems occur or the connection was aborted!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private URI setBaseProps(URIBuilder uri) {
    URI built = null;

    uri.setScheme(props.protocol())
            .setHost(props.host())
            .setPort(props.port());
    try {
        built = uri.build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return built;
}
```

All methods throw checked exceptions in method signature. And if some of those exceptions will be cached `HttpResponse` will be `null` that can produce on service `NullPointerException`.

How to avoid this?

Is it be good to wrap response to Optional and check it on service?

Thanks!

Comment: Return a HTTP 4xx or 5xx error response instead, depending on what the error is

Answer (score 2):

Passing around the response object from one class to another is not a good idea, it would be better to build a DTO and return it to the invoking class.

If you need to return the response object then you can:

- Throw an exception (your own or an http client exception) to the service invoking this method and handle the exception in there.
- Build an empty response object, set the [status](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) of the response and let the service invoking this method handle that status.

Comment: instead of an empty response a error response might make more sense in this context with the correct HTTP code set as well on the HTTPResponse.